# Calculating nearest point from a road, its name, distance and what road it intersects

Tags: postgis

I have a road and I need to calculate the nearest restaurant from it, its distance, its name and which road it is on(the restaurant). I have done all the things above except for the last one. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
 SELECT a.name, b.name, ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) AS distance
    FROM roads a, restaurants b
    WHERE a.name='Roehampton'
    ORDER BY distance ASC
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Sorry, is the question how to find which road a restaurant is on? Having the where clause with Roahampton Lane is a bit confusing. Also, please don't write things like any1, this is a professional forum, and text speak is not really appropriate :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific way to make use of index while searching for nearest neighbors, it's `<->`, and as maximilien said you should use the road table again. If the restaurant is not exactly on the road, try a nearest neighbors search again:

```
WITH restaurant AS (
   SELECT a.name, b.name, ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) AS distance, b.geom
   FROM aufgabe5.osm_roads a, aufgabe5.italian_restaurants b
   WHERE a.name='Roehampton Lane'
   ORDER BY a.geom <-> b.geom ASC
   LIMIT 1
)
SELECT res.*, roads.name as restaurant_road
FROM restaurant res, aufgabe5.osm_roads roads
ORDER BY res.geom <-> roads.geom ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you alot. :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to add another time the road table and look for St_intersects with restaurant geom ...

something like this :

```
SELECT c.name, a.name, b.name, ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) AS distance
    FROM aufgabe5.osm_roads a, aufgabe5.italian_restaurants b, aufgabe5.osm_roads c
    WHERE a.name='Roehampton Lane'
    AND St_intersects(b.geom, c.geom)
    ORDER BY distance ASC
    LIMIT 1
```

or you take the query you already wrote and you juste reverse your search as you have the restaurant name (CTE could be usefull here) ...